# PHP page output/echo always null, no generated error logs

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to create an extremely basic script that can function as a REST API. I've been having a lot of trouble getting any output to show on the page. In the code below you can see a couple of the commented methods I've tried to get an output. If I remove the printf while loop and just use the `responseData = json_encode($result)` line, I get a JSON output in the proper format but only containing null values. (Table columns have the appropriately named table headers but nothing else, no data is returned). For the record, the SQL statements, *are* being properly executed without error. The below script generates no PHP.log errors when run. If I change the SQL to an insert statement I can see the resulting values in the database. So whatever is going on here is some issue with simply outputting those values to the page.

This is the code for the entire page script I am using;

```
<?php
define("PROJECT_ROOT_PATH", __DIR__);
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USERNAME", "testuser");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "testpw");
define("DB_DATABASE", "testgb");

$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$uri = explode( '/', $uri );

/** Basic Input Filter **/
    function input_filter($data) {
        $data= trim($data);
        $data= stripslashes($data);
        $data= htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
 
    /**
     * Get URI elements.
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    function getUriSegments()
    {
        $uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
        $uri = explode( '/', $uri );
 
        return $uri;
    }
    
    function sendOutput($data, $httpHeaders=array())
    {
        header_remove('Set-Cookie');
 
        if (is_array($httpHeaders) && count($httpHeaders)) {
            foreach ($httpHeaders as $httpHeader) {
                header($httpHeader);
            }
        }
 
        echo $data;
        exit;
    }
    
    /**
     * "/[usertoken]/read" Endpoint - retrieve orders from db
     */
    
    function readAction()
    {
        $strErrorDesc = '';
        $requestMethod = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
        $arrQueryStringParams = parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query);
 
        if (strtoupper($requestMethod) == 'GET') {
            try {
                $intLimit = 100;
                if (isset($arrQueryStringParams['limit']) && $arrQueryStringParams['limit']) {
                    $intLimit = $arrQueryStringParams['limit'];
                }
                $intItemId = 0;
                if (isset($arrQueryStringParams['itemid']) && $arrQueryStringParams['itemid']) {
                    $intItemId = $arrQueryStringParams['itemid'];
                    echo $intItemId;
                }
                $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
                if ($conn->connect_error)
                {
                    die("Connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
                }
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM verified_orders WHERE itemid=?;";
                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                    die("Statement preparation failed.");
                } else {

                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "d", $intItemId);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        while ($row = $result -> fetch_row()) {
                            printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
                        }
                    }
                    /*$responseData = json_encode($result);*/
                }
            } catch (Error $e) {
                $strErrorDesc = $e->getMessage().'.';
                $strErrorHeader = 'HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error';
            }
        } else {
            $strErrorDesc = 'Method not supported';
            $strErrorHeader = 'HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity';
        }
 
        // send output
        if (!$strErrorDesc) {
            /*echo $responseData;
        } else {
            echo $responseData;*/
        }
    }
    if (isset($uri[2]) && $uri[2] != 'user') {
        header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
        exit();
    }
    if ($uri[3] == "read") {
        readAction();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Database API changes and misleading `parse_str()`

**updated**: There were a few errors going on in the end, combined with a lack of logs, resulting in a messy thread; I've updated this answer postmortem, to consolidate the solutions and realizations.

---

There seemed to be some problems with the database access (mixed forms of *mysqli*-fetching) and potentially false expectations, due to **assoc**iative vs **num**eric results (`$row[0]`, `$row[1]` were attempted in *assoc* mode). In the end, the entire set of **Mysqli** connect/prepare/query/fetch-calls were replaced with *known good* PDO variants; namely:

```
    if (!($conn = new PDO(sprintf('mysql:dbname=%s;host=%s', DB_DATABASE, DB_HOST), DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, [ PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ])))
        throw new Exception('Connection failed');

    if (!($stmt = $conn->prepare('
                SELECT * 
                  FROM verified_orders 
                 WHERE itemid = :itemid
              ORDER BY itemid
    '))) throw new Exception('Prepare failed');

    if (!$stmt->execute([ 'itemid' => $intItemId ]))
        throw new Exception('Execute failed');

    if (!($data = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE )))
        throw new Exception('Fetch failed');
```

Which is not to say that the `mysqli`-variants itself couldn't have been fixed. The problem just wasn't readily apparent.

The PDO database calls solved most problems, but not the absence of any value in the `$intItemId` variable (which is used in the SELECT query). That variable lived downstream from `$arrQueryStringParams`, which in turn was ment to be set here:

```
$arrQueryStringParams = parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query);
```

At first glance this looked fine, however the `parse_str()` function produces **no return value**. It actually injects the results into the 2nd argument, which in this case was a stray variable called `$query` (which wasn't used anywhere else at all).

The proper syntax for `parse_str()` would be:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $arrQueryStringParams);
```

### Original attempts at a solution

---

You're using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to fetch the query results (note the **assoc**iative).

This means the results won't end up in `$row[0]`, `$row[1]`, ... But instead `$row` is an associative array based on the column names, such as `$row['itemid']`.

*offtopic note: you should remove the `;` at the end of your SQL query. It can be a part of a* SQL script command *, where it denotes the end of a statement, but it isn't considered part of a single query.*

### update

Try replacing

```
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    while ($row = $result -> fetch_row()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
    }
}
```

with

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
}
```

See if that fixes the problem.

---

if it does not then check the logfiles and show the output of  `var_dump($x)` for `$row`, `$result`, `$stmt` and `$conn`.
And then repeat that process again after replacing the SQL with:

```
$sql = "SELECT 123 AS num, 'abc' AS str, ? AS inputval";
```

### update 2

Weird results, without anything to go on debugging wise, its probably best to try the following. (Temporarily) remove all your code starting at the line:

```
/** Basic Input Filter **/
```

and from there, all the way to the end of the file. Basically only leaving your `define`s; and then copy/paste the following at the bottom of the file, and then try to visit the page in your webbrowser, see what it prints.

```
try {
    echo 'A';
    if (!($conn = new PDO(sprintf('mysql:dbname=%s;host=%s', DB_DATABASE, DB_HOST), DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, [ PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ])))
        throw new Exception('Connection failed');
    echo 'B';
    if (!($stmt = $conn->prepare('
                SELECT * 
                  FROM verified_orders 
                 WHERE itemid = :itemid
                    OR 1=1
              ORDER BY itemid
                 LIMIT 20
    '))) throw new Exception('Prepare failed');
    echo 'C';
    if (!$stmt->execute([ 'itemid' => 1 ]))
        throw new Exception('Execute failed');
    echo 'D';
    if (!($data = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE )))
        throw new Exception('Fetch failed');
    echo 'E';
    echo PHP_EOL . '<br>';
    var_dump( $data );
    echo PHP_EOL . '<br>';
    echo 'F';
} catch (Throwable $e) { echo PHP_EOL . '<br>Exception: ' . htmlentities($e->getMessage()); }
Exit(0);
```

Comment: I've tried other methods which do not use ```mysqli_fetch_assoc```, you can see some of the commented out lines in my code. When I do ```$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt); $responseData = json_encode($result);``` instead I am still getting null values returned.

For the record, changing ```$row[0]``` to ```$row['itemid']``` still does not output anything to the page.

Comment: i've added some stuff to the answer above

Comment: I've done all three of the things you suggested here and none of them cause anything different to occur. The var_dump result doesnt show in the logs or on the page. Page is still blank with no output. Logs are still empty.

Comment: Weird stuff. I've added another method in the answer again, try that if you haven't found it yet.

Comment: Running the code in Update 2 yields ```ABC
Exception: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined```
As a side note there is no database entry with the primary_key or "itemid" of 1 in my database. Not sure if that is relevant to the error thrown.

Comment: Looked up the error. Seems to be an issue where the parameters don't match the table structure. There are 7 columns in my DB, not just "itemid".

From what I can tell that error is in no way related to the problem I'm experiencing with being unable to get an output to my page - because once again, if I change the SQL in my original code to a create or update statement, I can see the changes reflected in the db. So I know my SQL is being properly executed. The output is just not echoing to the page.

Comment: You have the `echo responseData` stuff commented out; but yes, i see now that that `HY093` error is my fault; i wrote `$stmt->execute([ 'itemid' => 1 ]))` the word `itemid` there should have been `id`

Comment: Yes. I commented out the code that normally sets the responseData variable;
```$responseData = json_encode($result);```

In order to test the forloop and print method of output, in an attempt to see what was wrong. Ideally, I would like whatever output to be in JSON format, but it matters not to me at this point how it gets there. The problem is that I just can't get an output of any kind no matter what I do. I am suspecting that the issue may lie with the ```headers()``` call but to me my usage of it looks correct.

Comment: yea thats why i had you remove all code (except credentials) earlier. After changing the `itemid`->`id` does my block of code provide more output than just `ABC` now ?

Comment: It does. It outputs ABCDEF and a whole bunch of data from my database. Any idea why this works and my code doesn't?

Comment: No not yet, i just figured it was worth trying it with some db code that i know works; i generally do not use the mysqli variants. I guess your next step should be to re-introduce your old code back into the mix, piece by piece, and see when it breaks, to narrow down the problem area. Or if you prefer, you could use this bit of DB code, and use that to replace half your original code (its basically the same as your old code from line `$conn = ` up to the `catch` line.). You'd only have to adjust the SQL a little bit , removing the `OR` and `LIMIT` directives i added in there.

Comment: I've tried to replace my db code with yours, however I'm still running into some odd issues I don't understand. I've never seen a sql statement structured this way so I dont know what it's actually doing, or how to modify it for my own purposes. If I remove the line ```OR 1=1``` the page stops working entirely.

Comment: specifically the statement construction and execution:
```if (!($stmt = $conn->prepare('
SELECT * 
FROM verified_orders 
WHERE itemid = :id
OR 1=1
ORDER BY itemid
LIMIT 20
'))) throw new Exception('Prepare failed');
if (!$stmt->execute([ 'id' => 1 ]))
throw new Exception('Execute failed');```
how can I change this to a comparison to a variable which comes from the URI?
I've tried replacing the ```'id' => 1``` with ```'id' = $intItemId``` and just ```$intItemId``` and neither works. Changing the value of 1 on that line to something else also doesnt seem to do anything.

Comment: Remove the `OR 1=1` and the `LIMIT 20`; changing the `[ 'id' => 1 ]` to `[ 'id' => $someVariable ]` will work then. I added the `OR 1=1` to neutralize your `itemid=:id`-check (1=1 will always match no matter what), to ensure we'd get some records back. And i added the `LIMIT 20` to make sure it wouldnt return 50.000 rows if theres a lot of data in your DB (as i have no idea what it is)

Comment: Removing the OR clause causes the page to simply return blank. It doesnt matter what I set id or itemid to. I set it explicitly to a bunch of known-good index values and it still doesn't output anything to the page. Thankfully though, it is giving me an error log now; ```PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Fetch failed in /home/username/sitename/api.php:63```

Where lines 62 and 63 are;
```if (!($result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE )))
     throw new Exception('Fetch failed');```

Comment: What is the SQL set to ? and the `execute` line.

Comment: ```if (!($stmt = $conn->prepare('
SELECT * 
FROM verified_orders
WHERE itemid=:id
ORDER BY itemid
'))) throw new Exception('Prepare failed');
if (!$stmt->execute([ 'id' => $intItemId ]))
throw new Exception('Execute failed');```

Comment: Seems likely that the `$intItemId` is the problem, are you sure that value is set at that point in the code ? -- If you pick a random itemid number that exists in your database, lets say for example 124, try adding `$intItemId = 124;` on the line **before** the `execute` line. And if that still doesn't work, then try `$intItemId = '124';`

Comment: that part looks alright; basically grabs the value of `$arrQueryStringParams` (if it has one). the problem lies further up; `$arrQueryStringParams = parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query);` is likely the problem (though that may depend on your php version aswell). Try changing that line to just: `parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $arrQueryStringParams);`

Comment: Nice catch. With that pointed out I managed to resolve my issue. Instead of using ```$arrQueryStringParams = parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query);```
I'm simply reading the itemid value directly into its variable with $_GET using this code:
```$intItemId = htmlspecialchars($_GET['itemid']);``` And now all seems to be functioning as expected.
Thanks for all the help. :) Accepting this as solution to the problem.

Comment: Nice work. I've summarized our comments into the answer so it covers the whole thing.